# jsf 1.2 update form without submit value

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I have a form with JSF 1.2 & RichFaces 3.3.4.

Currently I'm able to use AJAX for update value. When I update the form (by clicking element value1) I properly update element value2, but the value1, that updates the form, is submitted.

**I would like to update the element value2 of the form without submitting the element value1.**
It is possible?

```
<h:form id="formId">
        <h:selectOneMenu id="value1" value="#{searchCriteria.value1}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="---" itemValue="#{null}" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="a" itemValue="a" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="b" itemValue="b" />
            <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{searchCriteria.changeAction}"
                reRender="value2" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <h:selectOneMenu id="value2" value="#{searchCriteria.value2}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{searchCriteria.valueList}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <a4j:commandButton action="#{searchCriteria.search}" value="Search"
            reRender="formId" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Does value2 depend on value1? If yes I don't see how you expect that to work.

Comment: yes, the value2 depends on value1. actually it works but when I change  the value of value1 it is submitted on the form and value2 is updated. I don't want value1 is submitted but I want value2 is updated.

Comment: If value2 depends on value1 then you cannot update value2 without value1, which means it has to submitted.